# Search by amount laravel

Tags: laravel

How can I find a record by the sum of the field values ?

I tried it like this, but there is no result

```
->where(DB::raw('sum(two_place,ona_place)'), '>', 5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Sum()` is an aggregate function, that will be used in context of grouping data. you should add the columns together instead.

```
->where(DB::raw('two_place + ona_place'), '>', 5)
```